# Flutter container write text over background image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to make a design like following

[image]

I build the base layout with background image. Following is the code to achieve that. Now i want to put "Grocery store" Text on top of this image and other widgets. How can i do that ?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  height: 190.0,
  width: size.width,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    horizontal: 16.0,
  ),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                width: size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(https://www.exampledomain.com/images/background.jpg),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                // child: ????
                
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
child: Container(
                width: size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(https://www.exampledomain.com/images/background.jpg),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Text('Grocery store'),
                //padding: <-- Using to shift text position a little bit for your requirement
              ),
```

Answer (score 2):

`Stack`/`Align` is your friend.

Take a look here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Here is a basic example (based in your code):

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 190.0,
            width: size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 16.0,
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          width: size.width,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  "http://www.exampledomain.com/images/background.jpg"),
                              //fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),

                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text("Grocery store"))
      ]
    );
  }
```